# Google RE2 regex expression using gas

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I need to search for a text That begins with { and ends with } note that I need to search only if there is {=CAT some text here} and not {some other text}

I used Google apps script find text

text.findText("{=CAT.*}")

Comment: Try `"\{=CAT[^}]*}"`

Comment: is =CAT immediately after `{` or somewhere between `{` and `}`?

Comment: @Wiktor  Shouldn't it be double escaped `"\\{=CAT[^}]*}"`?

Comment: Maybe, I just copied OP's code.